# How to preview my php file with firefox in bluefish?

Tags: php, firefox, bluefish

I have installed bluefish-2.2.7 in win7,my firefox is installed "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe".
I think that my firefox command was set properly.

[image]

When to click the button "preview in browser" ,it ran across the message.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd think you'll need a web server to view PhP files in your browser, you can easily install a local webserver like WAMP if you're unsing Windows

Answer (score 0):

go to edit > preferences > output parser
create a new one call it whatever you want make sure to write in the command section the following.
php '%f' && firefox 'localhost/%n'

you can watch my video on youtube
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gwtzqtPB9Yw